# Convert the UTC datetime to any other time zone dynamically in php

Tags: php, html

I want to convert the UTC datetime to any other time zone.its working fine.
But it showing only for one time zone,so to view the other time zone need to change the code every time.
i want to  convert the UTC datetime to any other time zone dynamically.may be by selecting drop down or some other way.

```html
    <?php
$date = new DateTime('2017-11-15 01:00:00 +00');
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can timezone by this code where you can change the `$timezone` variable value from your dropdown.

```
$timezone=  'Asia/Calcutta';
$date = new DateTime('2017-11-15 01:00:00 +00');
$date = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone($timezone));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: But even giving the $timezone variable every time we need to change the code again,right? suppose currently its Asia/Calcutta but i want for Africa/Abidjan,in this case code need to change,so how to make in dynamic,any idea pls share?

Comment: So there you can use a global/session/post variable for this case and assign the value to $timezone like  `$timezone = $_POST['timezone']` or `$timezone = $_SESSION['timezone']`

Comment: and if you want to change the timezone permanently then you can change in php.ini file and store this timezone in the database for a better approach.